# adjust flavor from inexpensive brandy

Tags: flavor

I put cheap brandy in my sauce for stew and it smells like gasoline. Can you adjust this in any way? Of course I made enough for a big group coming over tonight!

Comment: **Never** put alcohol you wouldn't drink in your food. That's my advice for "next time." And yes, that means absolutely no "cooking wine" (my "sherry I cook with" is a large bottle of inexpensive sherry, not Harvey's Bristol Cream but not something terrible, loaded with salt and labeled "cooking sherry") As for this time, I think Lars has it right, other than "throw it all out and start over." ...at least I assume you don't drink "gasoline brandy."

Answer (score 2):

Well, the good thing is, what you smell is everything that left your stew in order to float around in the kitchen. My attempt, with no guarantee for success, would be to seriously reduce the sauce down to jus/gravy and then fill it up with water again. Then use some cream to soften any remaining taste.